Can I use multiple Gpus when reasoning images with SDXL model on comfyUI
When I used comfyUI to reason pictures, I used aws EC2 and A10 GPU on the machine. It took about one minute for workflow to generate an image.It's too slow.Can I deploy multiple Gpus to make image generation faster
I noticed this while playing with Easy Diffusion’s face fix, upscale options. With only one GPU enabled, all these happens sequentially one the same GPU. But with more GPUs, separate GPUs are used for each step, freeing up each GPU to perform the same action on the next image.However, this does not speed up the production of an image

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
